# @font-face not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, font-face

> http://fiddle.jshell.net/JamesKyle/TKhq8/show/light/

If you view this page you can see that I used a [Font-Squirrel-Generated](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) `@font-face` for `Franchise` it seems to work in every browser except Firefox, any ideas as to why this is?

PS I have looked around and still am not finding an answer

Comment: I don't have a solution, but not sure about it working in every other browser.  
In both IE9 and Opera 10.6, the text is white so I can't see it until I select it - is that intended?  
IE9 shows the text as Times New Roman or similar.  
Opera appears to have picked up the custom font.

Comment: well every other browser I tested, and IE9 is having a different bug because of all the text-shadows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're linking to a font that's on a different host and doesn't send the right CORS headers.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control and http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/11/troubleshooting-font-face-problems